# How to show image as the same size when they are not

Tags: angularjs, image, css

I have a web application in which the administrators can load any kind of images which will be shown in the site.
The issue is that the images have different size and dimentions...  But the idea is that the user that visit the site can see all the images in a similar size.
What do you suggest? And how?
The front end is in angularjs and the backend in java with sprint.
Is good to set an specific size? or maybe and specific height and that the width ajust it to the image dimention?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: I think this might help you, so you can give the user the aspect ratio you want to use in you app. [CROPPER](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/)... Remember all images in a the same aspect ratio ca be displayed in the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.img {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:  100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-size:     cover;
}

<div class="img" style="background-mage:url('http://i.imgur.com/tI5jq2c.jpg');"></div>
<div class="img" style="background-mage:url('http://i.imgur.com/37w80TG.jpg');"></div>
<div class="img" style="background-mage:url('http://i.imgur.com/B1MCOtx.jpg');"></div>
```

Comment: Nice use of background images with `background-size:cover`, but maybe this answer should have an explanation to go with it, that will help understand why you are suggesting it?

Comment: Instead you can use Pixels: background-size:75px 75px;